# Python Selenium and Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, docker-compose

I'm trying to create multiple containers with RPAs using selenium and Python, how can I do this without installing python and its libraries in each container? Like a base container with all dependencies and I can export these dependencies to the other containers. Or it cannot be done?

```
 services:
  chromedriver:
    container_name: chromedriver
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    shm_size: 2gb
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900
    restart: always
  bank_1:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-bank1
    container_name: bank_1
    command: python3 bank_1.py
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - chromedriver
  bank_2:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-bank1
    container_name: bank_2
    command: python3 bank_2.py
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    depends_on:
      - chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is to create an image and host it on DockerHub/ECR. When you change the code, you re-build the image and push a new version, meaning that the dependencies will be re-fetched once. And then your docker-compose services will reference this remote image as many times as needed.

To automate re-building the image, you can use tools like CircleCI or GitHub Actions.

(If you are only ever running this locally, then you may be able to skip the CI and DockerHub pieces and just build the image on your computer.)

Note also that you would typically not duplicate the service itself in the compose file, but rather use [`docker service scale`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_scale/) or a reverse proxy like [traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/quick-start/) to manage multiple identical instances.